# Colorización de corchetes de Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, color

¿Existe algo en Visual Studio 2022 para pintar las líneas entre corchetes igual que en Visual Studio Code?

[image: ejemplo de líneas de colores entre corchetes]

Comment: Encontré una extensión llamada Viasfora y con eso se pintan las líneas entre corchetes o llaves.

Answer (score 0):

Como no recibí respuesta rápida, seguí buscando y encontré una extensión llamada Viasfora y con eso se pintan las líneas entre corchetes o llaves.[image: Extensión Viasfora]